# iOS 16 App Intent not Discoverable by Siri

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, ios16

I'm implementing the new iOS 16 AppIntents framework and it works fine except when I try to trigger it with Siri, which just pulls up results from the web. Here's a very simple version I made on an empty project.

```swift
import Foundation
import AppIntents

@available(iOS 16.0, *)

struct ShowMeBooks: AppIntent {

    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Show me my books"

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentPerformResult {
        let x = 1 + 1
        return .finished(dialog: "Here are your books")
    }
}



@available(iOS 16.0, *)

struct SouthwestShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {

    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: ShowMeBooks(),
            phrases: ["Show me my books on \(.applicationName)"]
        )
    }
}
```

I expected the shortcut to be run after calling Siri on the simulator and saying "Show me my books on MyNewTestApp". Am I missing something or does the framework not support Siri yet?

Comment: I have the same issue on Xcode 14 beta 6. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first Xcode 14 Beta had this problem where metadata extraction was not working if the Xcode selected using `xcode-select` is older than Xcode 14. Maybe that's what's happening to you as well.

Try setting the Xcode 14 Beta as your main Xcode instance using `xcode-select`. I also recommend doing a clean build and deleting your app from the simulator.

This issue has been supposedly fixed as of Xcode 14 Beta 3 though.

Comment: I changed to Xcode 14 Beta 3 and it only worked once, surprisingly enough. I retried it after a clean build and deleting all data but couldn't replicate it. I think I'll just wait until the next version.

Comment: @programr I still have this issue in Xcode 14 RC. Is it fixed on your side?

Comment: Same here, in XCode 14 RC

Comment: @huync It's not working on Xcode 14 simulators but I got it to work on my personal device just fine. I was told in the Apple Developer Forums that [they're working on it](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709321?login=true).

Comment: @programr it is not working on my device. So sad!

Comment: still an issue in Xcode 14.3